# Update Query with subquery and If statement

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, case

I've got a temporary table full of my drop shippers' on-hand inventory which I'd like to use in order to update my woocommerce website. I'm using the supplier's SKU as a key , but woocommerce has this buried so I have to use a subquery on the join.

```
update yra_postmeta
    join supplier_stock on 
        (select meta_value from yra_postmeta where meta_key='_supplier_sku') = supplier_stock.supplier_sku
set yra_postmeta.meta_value = CASE WHEN supplier_stock.stock < 1 AND yra_postmeta.meta_key = '_stock_status' THEN 'outofstock'
                      WHEN supplier_stock.stock >=1 AND yra_postmeta.meta_key = '_stock_status' THEN 'instock'
                      end
```

I'm getting "error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'yra_postmeta' for update in FROM clause" which seems to be quite common, and there seem to be some solutions out in the wild, but I can't seem to make any of them work for this particular query? Any Ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work, so you'll want to test it really well.  But could you change the join so that it used an and.  Then you wouldn't have a circular reference to the table your editing.

```
UPDATE yra_postmeta
JOIN supplier_stock ON meta_key = '_supplier_sku'
     AND meta_value = supplier_stock.supplier_sku  

SET yra_postmeta.meta_value = CASE 
    WHEN supplier_stock.stock < 1
        AND yra_postmeta.meta_key = '_stock_status'
        THEN 'outofstock'
    WHEN supplier_stock.stock >= 1
        AND yra_postmeta.meta_key = '_stock_status'
        THEN 'instock'
    END
```